# Tomcat, Spring, Schedulers - memory leaks

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, memory-leaks, spring-scheduled

I have some classes with methods annotated with Scheduled annotation.

When I stop/undeploy/redeploy this app in the Tomcat, I have such message:

```
"The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm):
/my-app
/my-app
/my-app"
```

I've tried to "autowire" ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in the ContextClosed handler and stop it using shutdown() method. But it doesn't help. It seems to scheduled methods (threads) are not controlled by the Tomcat.

I've tried to set taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false) also.

When I get dump of heap I see only classes (instances) which contain Scheduled methods and classes associated with them.

It leads to problem with our server () which in few days stops to respond on the requests.

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(400);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }
}
```

Schedulers:

```
@Component
public class HistoryCleaner {

    @Autowired
    private HistoryService historyService;
    @Autowired
    private AppProperties app;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void cleanHistory() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When you created the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean did you try to configure the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` in order to not wait for tasks completition before close? Something like this `taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);` and then call the shutdown?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Yes, I did. But it didn't help.

Comment: Mytsykov that's strange. Did you use a profiler to understand which classes are still alive?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata yes - instances of classes with Scheduled methods (or assosiated with them, for example injected services)

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I made two dump of heap (when application is alive and after application is stopped/undeployed) with help of visualVM

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. (add some code, configuration etc. ).

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing the same behavior with `@Scheduled` methods in Spring Boot 2.0.5, where any beans which are supposed to be recreated via `@DirtiesContext` during integration tests, are left alive, causing memory leaks.